# Are there any risks when adding new extended attributes?

Tags: filesystems

Using superuser privileges, I attach a new extended attribute, a 32-digit UUID, to every last file on my file system.

Could there be any risks attached to this operation by itself? (Other than increasing disk usage.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some context. What operating system are you using? What filesystem? How would you add the attribute, exactly? Would you also change system files like device files? Is this a UEFI setup? If so, do you have the firmware mounted under `/sys`? Would you also change _those_ files? We can't help unless you explain in more detail.